# Simple algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, banach-algebras

The following is taken from Dales' *Banach Algebras and Automatic Continuity*;

[image]

For reference, $A^\bullet=\{a\in A:a\neq 0\}$, $A^2=\{a^2:a\in A\}$, $AA=\{ab:a,b\in A\}$, $aA=\{ab:b\in A\}$, etc.

None of the algebras are assumed to be unital, unless stated otherwise.

I'm struggling to follow the proof of 1.3.52(i):

- It's claimed that $A^2\neq A$ implies $I\neq A$. Are we using the definition of simplicity here? Should it perhaps be $A^2\neq 0$? Or should the definition of simplicity be amended to $A^2\neq A$?
- Why does $AaA\neq 0$ imply $AaA=A$? If this is a direct appeal to simplicity, I don't see why $AaA$ is an ideal.

Comment: Are these algebras assumed unital?

Comment: @JacobManaker They are not, let me clarify this in the question body, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: For your last question, the algebra $A$ generated by $M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ does not satisfy $A^2 = 0$, since $M^2 \neq 0$, but it is easy to see each matirx in $A$ is of the form $a M + b M^2$, and any matrix of this form cubes to $0$.

Comment: I added the *Banach algebra* tag. The question seems relatively basic, but most users familiar with simple algebras assume a multiplicative neutral element. Adding this tag may make it easier for the question to get the attention from users who won't break a sweat answering it, or quickly find a duplicate (if one exists).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about your notation?  On p. 29 of the book, for a subset $S$ of $A$, the author defines $S^{[2]}$ to be the set of all products $xy$ with $x,y\in S$ and defines $S^2$ to be the linear span of $S^{[2]}$.  More generally, the author defines $ST$ to be the linear span of all products $st$, $s\in S,t\in T$.  This follows standard notation in ring theory.  In particular, $A^2$ is always an ideal.  For a ring with no ideals save $0$ and $A$, the conditions $A^2=A$ and $A^2\ne 0$ are equivalent.

If $a\in A$, the (usual and also this book's) meaning of $AaA$ is the ideal generated by all products $xay$, $x,y\in A$, that is, the set of elements $\sum_{j=1}^n x_jay_j$.  This set is an ideal, so if $AaA\ne0$, it must be $A$ by simplicity.  Moreover, $I=\{\,a\in A\mid AaA=0\,\}$ is an ideal, so it is either $0$ or $A$.  If it is $A$, then $A^3=0$, which contradicts the assumption that $A^2=A$.  Thus $I=0$.

Comment: Well that makes a lot of sense. I missed that line on page 29 (which, in my defense, is a bit hidden :P), and I'm not very familiar with ring theory, so I assumed the wrong thing for $A^2$.

I get it now, my notation was just very off. Thank you so much!